# Move my MERN app (developped on windows) on a ubuntu machine and access it via LAN network

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, lan, mern

It's my first time here so please bear with me :)

Basically i developped a full stack MERN web application on my windows 10 machine (node js, express js and Mongodb in the backend + database and react js for the frontend), to run each one of them for now i use vscode (nodemon server for the backend and npm start for the front) all are running on my localhost on different ports.

what i need to do is to move that MERN app to an ubuntu machine and make it accessible via LAN network of that ubuntu continuously.

i guess i need to use git to move the app from windows to ubuntu? (correct me if i'm wrong) but how to make it run correctly there? and should i install a specific server to run it all on the LAN?

Thank you for the help in advance !

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It would be helpful to include any steps you have tried so far and where exactly you got stuck. Once you have your source code in the new machine (yes, you can use `git clone`), are you able to compile and run all you need?

Comment: Hi!

I actually finished my app today so i just started the part of transfering the code and all the rest.

I used Git to get the code on the ubuntu machine (i was not sure it was the right thing to do) and proceded to install the needed packages. The code is still not runing I am trying to check if i missed any packages or so.

about the LAN part i really don't know where to start, should i install a https server or something along this?

Comment: First please make sure your MERN stack is working fine in your new machine.for lan you don't need to do anything extra just make sure that your MERN SERVER IS UP(making request) and also your local ip address is reachable.